# Delete first row of all csv's before concatenation python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My current issue right now is that I have a program automatically generating csv files but the data in the first rows contain commas. I'm trying to delete the first row of each csv from the folder and then concatenate into a large csv so that way the data is not automatically shifting to new columns when processing.

I know you can do read_csv("name", skiprows=1) for individuals but how to do this for a whole directory I'm not sure.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = r'C:'
folder = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv")) 

df = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in folder)
concatenated_df = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)

print(concatenated_df)
```

Comment: Change `df = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in folder)` to `df = (pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=1) for f in folder)`

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something small but couldn't get the syntax right.

Comment: maybe first you should use normal `for`-loop instead of list comprehesion. And when it will work then run as list comprehension